# Unity shaders. Get screen space quad-like sampling

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Want to get screen-space coords from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` of object's quad bounding it around
Trying to achieve this result not depending on screen position and camera angle
[image]
This is simple uv sampling from specific angle
I need to see the same result from the other side, but there is a uv seam on the other side
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a matcap UV to me. You can try searching for "Unity Matcap Shader" and see if something nice comes up. Here is the central part of the calculation (in the vertex shader):

```
o.uv = mul((float3x3)UNITY_MATRIX_V, UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.vertex)).xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
```

EDIT: So, you basically want screen-space UVs except with the object as the origin. I think the above solution should still work if you substitute the normal for the object space position.

```
o.uv = mul((float3x3)UNITY_MATRIX_V, v.vertex).xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
```

This will use the object-space position of the model, rotated into screen-space. It should work as long as the mesh origin is at its center. Note though that the range of the UV coords will depend on the size of the model (1 meter = 1 uv tile), so you might need to multiply it by some factor.

EDIT2: OK, so i'm starting to understand a bit more what you are trying to achieve. If you want the screen space UVs to be relative to the bounds of the object, then you will need to somehow pass the screen-space bounding box into the shader.

I suggest adding a float4 vector property to the material where XY is the bounds center, and ZW is the box dimensions, and then set it from code using something like `GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetProperty("_ScreenBounds", bounds);`. You will have to calculate the object's screen bounds inside the update method of a script. You can get bounds using [Renderer.bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html), and you can transform them into screen space using [Camera.WorldToScreenPoint()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html). Transform all corners of the bounding box and get the min/max points.

Inside the shader, you can calculate the regular screen-space UVs of the object, and then subtract the offset and divide by the dimensions.

I should warn you though that there is a small delay associated with sending data over to the GPU, so it is possible that you might experience a slight lag in updating the bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is a bit not what I wanted. When object is in the left top corner it differs in color when it is in the right bottom. It has a bit offset. I want to make it independent on camera angle and object position within the screen quad

Comment: Shortly, I want to know in pixel shader how far from center current pixel is getting the magnitude of uv vector. May be not correct solution, but a good challenge to know answer for future

Comment: is there a way to make it center independent?

Comment: If you just want pure screen-space coordinates, then you can just use ComputeScreenPos, or even just the clipspace position X/Y as UV. Here is a tutorial on screen space UVs: https://www.ronja-tutorials.com/2019/01/20/screenspace-texture.html

Comment: unity provides `_ScreenParams.xy` which is screen size in pixels

Comment: Yes, that is the size of the physical monitor in pixels. You can use it to correct for aspect ratio.